# How to control 200 RGB LEDs (on a light strip, able to address individually)?

Tags: led-strip

I want to make a grid of 10x20 RGB LEDs, and I think that RGB light strips might work. Can I power all of the LEDs (I'm not sure which kind I'll use but they won't be extremely bright) directly from an atmega microprocessor, still retaining the ability to address each individual strip. Is this possible? How do I wire it?

Comment: There are a zillion examples on the internet. Google ws2812 neopixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem: three LED colors, and 10 x 20 array,
implies current around 5 mA (give or take an order
of  magnitude) times 600.   So, 3 amperes of
current is to be expected.   Direct connection to
an 'atmega' limits your power to a rather lower
quantity, the power-pin current rating.

That is easily soluble: some RGB smart devices come with separate
power and data inputs, like WorldSem WS2812B[see here](http://www.world-semi.com/Certifications/WS2812B.html), and
come mounted on strips.   That means  power doesn't
literally come from the ATMEGA chip, but is a separate
circuit.

Those strips, though, have to be programmed, in ripple
fashion, one unit at a time.   A strip with 20 units
will take 20 times 24 bits, transmitted serially
at 'up to' 800 kHz, plus some overhead... roughly
20 x 80 us = 1.6 milliseconds.   You'll probably
notice the 'blink'.   A strip with 10 units will
re-program in 0.8 milliseconds.

The 'ATMEGA' family has many members; the ATMEGA328
is common, inexpensive, and has almost enough I/O pins
for the 10-unit strips solution (20 strips); it
has enough for the 20-unit strips, unless you need
many other functions.

So, yes, it is possible, in the sense that power supply,
ATmega CPU, and that number of RGB triples can be a
workable controlled array of lights.

Comment: 2812/6812 "Neopixel"-style RGB LED matrices are usually controlled via just one IO pin, as one long "string". You also did not  mention the software needed to control these LEDs. For the Arduino environment (which was not mentioned but might be a good starting point), there are some very extensive and feature-rich libraries, notably FastLED and the Adafruit Neopixel library.

Comment: 20x10=200. One chip consume from1 to 60 mA, depends on brightness. 60x200=12A. Data is connected in sequince, from chip to chip. Power source may be separate, just share ground with MCU. MCU output should be 5V.

Answer (score 1):

Making a a LED matrix from LED strips is an excellent idea.

One of the problems of long LED strips is the voltage drop if feeding current in from one end. Once you have 100 LEDs in series, the voltage drop will affect the colours differentially, and the strip reddens, as the blue LEDs lose voltage headroom at the far end.

In a 10x20 matrix, you can provide DC power to all the LED strips in parallel from one side, so have a maximum of only 10 or 20, or even both sides, so have only 5 or 10 powered in series.

Now that the LEDs are powered cleanly, you have to choose how to control them. The simplest, if your update time permits, is to daisy-chain the entire length, and control them all individually from one I/O pin on your AtMega. There are several libraries you can use to generate the control signals.